# How do I show a bootstrap modal from within a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a button on my page that when it is pushed it triggers some javascript functions to occur, and one of those javascript functions to open a bootstrap modal, but I can't seem to get it to work.  Here is my code... please help.

```
 //elsewhere on the form is the button that triggers the javascript
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" id="cancelPObtn" data-dismiss="modal">Yes, cancel it</a>

 <!-- CANCEL A PO MODAL -->
 <div class="modal hide fade" id="error-dialog" style="display: none;">
   <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</a>
        <h3>Cancel Purchase Order?</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-modal btn-cancel"  data-dismiss="modal">Yes, cancel it</a>
       <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Nevermind</a>
   </div>
 </div>




      $('.btn-danger').click(function(event) {
          if(some random conditional statement){
             //some stuff happens here
          }
          else{ 
                //Show form validation error modal-- I know this part is triggered but the modal will not show
                $("#error-dialog").modal("show");
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're missing `if () {` part of the conditional statement

Comment: I accidently removed the if() when I entered the question.  The real solution was I needed to remove  the style tag  style="display: none;" from the modal.

Comment: @JSilva If this was not really the problem with your question then please don't accept this answer. This just confuses people when they read this question.

Answer (score 7):

$("#error-dialog").modal("show");

This is the correct way, your code simply has an error. Go in to Chrome Console and run this command, it'll work.

Comment: Simple one liner, easy to use and functional. Thank you Andy!

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit hard to see what you want to do with this partial code, but here is a working code based on yours:

http://jsbin.com/oqomiv/1/edit